# 顔画像のデータをクラスタリングしたい

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook

私は開発環境Python(Jupyter notebook)を用いた国旗画像をクラスタリングするプログラムを用いて顔画像をクラスタリングできるプログラムに改良しようと思っています。

しかし、そのまま顔画像をセットしても分類してもらえません。

以下がソースコードです

```
import os
import shutil
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import data
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans


for path in os.listdir('C:/Clustering2/human_origin'):
img=Image.open(f'C:/Clustering2/human_origin/{path}')
img=img.convert('RGB')
img_resize=img.resize((200,100))
img_resize.save(f'C:/Clustering2/human_convert/{path}.jpg')


feature=np.array([data.imread(f'C:/Clustering2/human_convert/{path}') for path in os.listdir('C:/Clustering2/human_convert')])
feature=feature.reshape(len(feature),-1).astype(np.float64)


model=KMeans(n_clusters=15).fit(feature)


labels=model.labels_


for label,path in zip(labels,os.listdir('C:/Clustering2/human_convert')):
os.makedirs(f"C:/Clustering2/human_group/{label}",exist_ok=True)
shutil.copyfile(f"C:/Clustering2/human_origin/{path.replace('.jpg','')}",f"C:/Clustering2/human_group/{label}/{path.replace('.jpg','')}")
print(label,path)
```

以下がエラーコードです。

```
No such file or directory: 'C:/Clustering2/human_origin/img_136'
```

用意した画像に問題があると思い再三見直しましたが解決しませんでした。

Comment: `img=Image.open(f'C:/Clustering/flag_origin/{path}'`に拡張子が無いからではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます^^　最初に画像の読み込みの部分はすでにできていて画像のリサイズ、学習、ラベル付けまではできるのですが最後の部分がエラーになってしまいます。画像のフォルダ分けができないといった状況です。

Comment: @Юрияпеталова  実行しているソースコードと質問文中にあるソースコードは同じものですか？　エラーメッセージに出ているパスがソースコード中には無いものなので、別のソースコードを実行しているのではないかと疑っています。

Comment: ソースコードが間違っていたので直しました。すいません。

Comment: 上記のソースコードを実行した際に上記のエラーコードが出ている状況です。

Comment: `shutil.copyfile(...)` の部分で拡張子(`.jpg`)を削除している(`.../{path.replace('.jpg','')}`)のはなぜなのでしょう？

Comment: 国旗画像をクラスタリングしているときはpng画像であったため拡張子を変更する必要があったからです。（大元の画像は.pngであるため)

Comment: 今回の顔画像の場合は.jpg形式だったため拡張子を変更する必要がないことに気づきました。よって、無事解決することができました。質問、回答いただいた方々、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーメッセージ「No such file or directory: 'C:/Clustering2/human_origin/img_136'」
[直訳] 'C:/Clustering2/human_origin/img_136'というファイルもしくはディレクトリはありません
という内容ですから、「用意した画像に問題がある」のではなく、「用意した画像のファイルに問題(ファイル名が違っている、違うディレクトリに置いている等々)がある」と考えてください。

nekketsuuu氏がコメントしているように、質問のコード中には、"C:/Clustering/"で始まるファイルパスしか書かれていないのですから、'C:/Clustering2/human_origin/img_136'に関したエラーが発生するのは変です。
実行につかったプログラムのソースを確認してください。

Answer (score 0):

国旗画像の場合は元の画像が.png形式であったため、特徴抽出する前に.jpg形式に変更する処理をしていて、今回は顔画像のクラスタリングで.jpg形式のままだったので拡張子を変更する処理をカットしました。その結果、無事解決することができました。